# iOS swipe gesture not working when Search Display Controller is showing results

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Something really strange is happening in the Search View Controller (a normal View Controller with a Search Display Controller connected to a UISearchBar and a TableView) of my app and that is the swipe gesture (the one that takes you back to the View where you came from) is not working when Search Display Controller is showing results.

I mean, to be more explicit: when the table view is showing the results of the search made using the UISearchBar I can try and try again to swipe from left to right and nothing happens.

If I press the cancel button or the button that clears the text of the UISearchBar then everything works normally: I mean I can again use the swipe gesture (from the left side of the device screen to right side of the device screen) to get back to the view where I came from.

Anybody experiencing the same thing?

Comment: Hmmm... Is it maybe first responder at that point? I'd try adding a touches did begin and resign first responder with the search bar.

Comment: I am executing [searchBar resignFirstResponder]; in searchBarCancelButtonClicked, searchBarTextDidEndEditing and also in searchBarSearchButtonClicked. Is that ok?

Comment: I made my reply an answer so the code remains formatted. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't what's wrong with the `UISearchBar` or the `Search Display Controller` but when they become FirstResponder they disable the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` of the `navigationController`.

It results in not letting you user the swipe gesture to go back.

TO FIX THIS:

I added these two lines of code in my viewDidLoad method:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = true;
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I'm actually surprised it worked at all without declaring the delegate. Glad you found a fix.

Comment: I also had to add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in my header file. ;)